# Python 3.6 and Intel numpy issue

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6, intel

I wanted to test the Intel distribution of numpy (see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-distribution-for-python-and-intel-performance-libraries-with-pip-and).

I followed the simple installing procedure: pip install intel-numpy

The package was installed correctly. However, the simple "import numpy as np" raised the following error:

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

I am using Python 3.6.5 and my system is MacOs, but I got the very same error on Windows.

Does anyone know if Intel page is deprecated? Or if Intel packages are not compatible with Python 3.6.5?

PS: I know that Anaconda distribution install Intel distribution, by do I really need to use Anaconda?

Comment: Did you have any previous `numpy` installation? Where the ICC and MKL available to PATH at the time of the installation? Anyway, TBH while you do not really need, it is so much easier to use Anaconda that why bothering?

Comment: I installed from an empty virtual environment, so no previous numpy install. I see for Anaconda, I just wondered why I have to "bother" installing Anaconda distribution...

Comment: Because it offers a much easier way of installing packages with complex dependencies like NumPy

Comment: Your are missing the point here. I have used Anaconda in many professional projects....my question was more about the use of optimized Intel libraries and their installation from the official python package manager.